# Can I find a javascript tag/element using Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

How do i find if a javascript file is included using Capybara?

Answer (score 0):

```
all('script').find { |s| s[:src].match /ga\.js$/ }.should be_nil
```